# how to display google comparison chart vertically

Tags: php, google-visualization

in my project i need to show graph on particular place, i used to google bar charts for comparison, i get the graph but it appears on horizontally, but i need the graph in vertically, i tried from morning on wards but no luck, please help. Thanks in advance. Below is the my code

```
<script type="text/javascript">      
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
imagepath_comparison="";
function drawChart() {
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([<?=$data;?>]);
var options = {
title: 'GRAPH ANALYSIS',
vAxis: {title: "SUBJECTS"},
hAxis: {
title: "MARKS"

}
};

var chart3 = new google.visualization.BarChart            (document.getElementById("columnchart_material"));
google.visualization.events.addListener(chart3, 'ready', function () {
imagepath_comparison=chart3.getImageURI();
drawChart1();
});
chart3.draw(data, options);
}
</script>
```

Comment: Why don't you use `ColumnChart` for vertical comparison ?

Answer (score 1):

it was very simple thing need to change for displaying the results,i used ColumnChart in place of Barchart at that time my problem is solved.

my code after changing is

```
<script type="text/javascript">      
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
imagepath_comparison="";
function drawChart() {
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([<?=$data;?>]);
var options = {
title: 'GRAPH ANALYSIS',
vAxis: {title: "SUBJECTS"},
hAxis: {
title: "MARKS"

}
};

var chart3 = new google.visualization.BarChart               (document.getElementById("columnchart_material"));
google.visualization.events.addListener(chart3, 'ready', function () {
imagepath_comparison=chart3.getImageURI();
drawChart1();
});
chart3.draw(data, options);
}
</script>
```